# Action Mailer & Sidekiq, emails are stuck inside enqueued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, devise, sidekiq

I'm trying to setup my rails app with docker along with sidekiq in order to send emails. This is the setup I have:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails server puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=server.key&cert=server.crt'"
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - '.:/project'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/1
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

    elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "http.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "transport.host=127.0.0.1"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 1g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  redis:
    image: 'redis:6.2.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'

  sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -e development -q mailers -q default
    volumes:
      - '.:/project'
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/12

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

Sidekq.yml

```
:concurrency: 1
:queues:
  - mailers
```

application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

config.action_mailer.deliver_later_queue_name = 'mailers'

Sidekiq.configure_server { |c| c.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] } }
```

As you can see from the screenshot below, sidekiq and everything else works just fine.

[image]

I'm also using the devise and devise-async gems in order to signup users and to send out asynchronous emails with sidekiq:

```
gem 'devise'
gem "devise-async"
```

devise_async.rb

```
Devise::Async.setup do |config|
  config.enabled = true
end
```

But the issue is, when I sign up a user through the devise process the confirmation email never gets send. It seems to be stuck inside enqueued:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can send out the emails that are stuck inside the enqueued?

Comment: What does the Busy tab show?

Comment: Your web is using different Redis config from Sidekiq. DB 1 vs DB 12.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply @Mike Perham. I had to change this `environment: - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/12` to this `environment: - REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ=redis://redis:6379/1` and it works just fine now. If you want you can post it as an answer and I will accept it.